# How can I make sure my EditText always has focus?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

Whenever an activity starts, I want to make sure my EditText has focus and has the cursor inside. Basically I want to make sure the keyboard is up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the EditText tag in your xml layout, add the tag

```
<requestFocus />
```

You may also do the programatically by calling the method. editText.requestFocus.